# Well that was an easy Silver Constituent Badge to earn

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, election

I just got four Caucus and one Constituent badge.

I *think* all I did was click on the Moderator Elections link from here on Meta.

Comment: I just got the two `caucus` badges merely for going to stackoverflow.com :/  I didn't click any pages nor knew about the elections.

Comment: @MooingDuck that's probably because you participated at the last elections, to prove this theory go to the notification and see if the link ends with `.../election/2`

Comment: @ajax333221 Seems you are correct.  I got 2 caucus and a Constituent for the last  election as well.  Fun.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The four Caucus badges is a bug - should've been two. Two of them are now gone.

The Constituent badge would've been for the *last* election.

Comment: Hmm, I think I like getting grandfathered into new badges.  Nice.

Answer (score 7):

You think *that's* bad:

[image]

Comment: Mine looked very similar :)

Comment: hah, 19? I got 41!

Answer (score 5):

On the notification box, if you hover on the **election** links, you should be able to see from which election it was awarded (e.g https://stackoverflow.com/election/2)

> You've earned the "Caucus" badge for an **election**. See your
>   profile.
>
> You've earned the "Caucus" badge for an **election**. See your
>   profile.

If the links are all from different elections, there is no bug.