# Caucus is causing a raucous

Tags: bug, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Well that was an easy Silver Constituent Badge to earn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135201/well-that-was-an-easy-silver-constituent-badge-to-earn)

The [new Caucus badge](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/06/election-participation-badges/) seems to have been awarded twice per election to some users.

For example: https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1973/caucus?userid=405015