# How did I just earn two Caucus badges?

Tags: support, badges, election

Can someone explain to me why I just earned two Caucus badges? I have been a member for less than a year and I only remember visiting this year's elections page once.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[As Chichiray notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135222/how-did-i-just-earn-two-caucus-badges/135223#135223), you actually *could* have earned two of them.

But you didn't - check [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/844882/alex-lockwood?tab=badges), there's only one.

We accidentally [awarded these twice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135201/well-that-was-an-easy-silver-constituent-badge-to-earn/135204#135204) initially, and during cleanup missed the Activity list - so even though it *says* you earned two, there's only one.

Comment: Ahh, OK. That must have been updated fairly recently then. When I last checked I had two.

Comment: Does that mean that you can't simply earn a second Caucus badge by visiting last year's election page? Must it be during an *active* election to earn the badge?

Comment: Yes, it has to be an *active* election ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Last election was November 2011 and you're registered at July 2011. So the chance is there that you've ever (accidently) visited the November 2011 election page.

Comment: Sounds probable. During the last election, there was a big, ugly banner on every page. Chances are that you clicked it at least once, even if it was only to make it go away.